# Access the default JSON.NET serializer in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a ASP.NET web API project and since it does not support having 2 body parameters, I use a JObject parameter and then extract the actual parameters from it. Like this.

```
Public bool mymethod(JObject data){
   myclassA a = data["a"].toObject<myclassA>();
   myclassA b = data["b"].toObject<myclassB>();
}
```

But the 2 class types implement ISerializable and I need the JSON.NET to ignore it. I have set up the default JSON.NET serializer to do that and it works fine when serialization is done automatically.

But I need to get a reference to the built in JSON.NET serializer so that I could use it like this in the above code.

```
myclassA b = data["b"].toObject<myclassB>(defaultSerializer);
```

Currently I create a new instance of the JSON.NET serializer and use it. But how can I get a reference to the default built in serializer in the asp.net WEB API ?

Also I cannot change anything in class types as this is sort of a legacy app that I'm converting to web api. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings);
```

That should give you the same serializer Web API uses.

Comment: Thanks, actually I'm using a slight variation of this. But this still calls JsonSerializer.Create() which creates a new instance of the serializer. I'm thinking if I could get reference to the serializer that has been already instantiated by the web api itself.

Comment: Web API creates a new serializer for each request. So that doesn't really mean anything. Json Serializers are very lightweight objects.

Comment: I had to use `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings`.

Comment: Thanks Dejan.  Or here's the whole enchilada.  System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings

Comment: This kept from from having to [DataContract] and [DataMember] attribute many items.  Instead of using "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject", using this kept the "backing field" style.  My code in the next comment:

Comment: string argAsJson = string.Empty;                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Create(System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings);
                using (var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
                {
                    using (var jsonWriter = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter(writer))
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, myObject);
                        argAsJson = writer.ToString();
                    }
                }