# AngularJS doesnt show the value of object's property

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

this should be straight forward, just cant figure out why it's not working.

I receive data in this format from Web API 2 (captured from Chrome's debugger):

[image]

AngularJS code to render the results
(vm.reportParameters contains that structure on the screenshot with 2 nodes):

```
<form>
    <div ng-repeat="param in vm.reportParameters" class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{param.Name}}" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The output (missing value of Name property, should display "Country"):

[image]

Any idea what I am missing here? **Why the value is not shown?**

```
// GET api/reports/5
// This action retrieves parameters of selected report by reportId
[ResponseType(typeof(ParametersModel))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string reportId)
{
    try
    {
        var manager = new ReportsManager();
        var model = manager.GetReportParameters(reportId);
        if (model == null || model.Parameters == null || model.Parameters.Count == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok<ParametersModel>(model);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

> This garbage-alike data has this weird format with all these k__XXXXX
>   things because I had various attributes applied to the model for XML
>   Deserialization (in C# code). After I removed all these Serialization
>   attributes, the model became normal and clean as expected. Go guess :)

Comment: yep, that's how Web API 2 returns data (the response object), that's why I am asking  :)

Comment: Wild...that's not how my collections are returned from WebAPI 2. What return type are you using on the controller method? Are you not using `IHttpActionResult`?

Comment: Seeing your endpoint will probably be helpful. I've never seen that much cruft in my response before. Usually it's just `{property: value, property: value}`, standard json.

Comment: @Lex, I added code snippet from Web API layer.

Comment: @Yatrix, mee too, first time I am using Web API 2, and this is what I get.

Comment: @monstro check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334382/net-webapi-serialization-k-backingfield-nastiness

Comment: Interesting. I still don't understand what's causing all that extra garbage on the returned collection, but I suspect that may be why you're experiencing the issue you are.

Answer (score 0):

Use without expression, **`ng-model`**

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="param.Name" />
```

Comment: @monstro sorry i missed ng-model

Comment: still no result, it seems accessing the property as we normally do (param.Name) doesn't work for some reason

Comment: question: when you use @monstro, you actually type that "@monstro" or you click somewhere? what is the purpose of using "@monstro"?

Comment: @monstro it's to alert the specific person that he's addressing them. Adding the name will give you a notification someone responded to you.

Comment: @Yatrix, and this notification appears in "Recent inbox messages" in red?
Do I have to manually type it, like I just did or is there a shortcut like "reply to.." ?

Comment: If you're responding to the person who started the question or answer thread, you can just reply (add comment). If you wanted to address me in _his_ answer, you should use the @ symbol.